# How to order a sorted array into columns when there are remainders with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of values in alphabetical order:

```
const arr = ['abcdefghijkl'].split('');
```

The order I want to get the letters in alphabetical orderBy columns in 1 flat collection.

*e.g by `3` cols:*

```
['a','e','i',
 'b','f','j',
 'c','g','k',
 'd','h','l']
```

we can do this pretty easy with fp lib like lodash:

```
const arr = 'abcdefghijkl'.split('');

function orderByCols(a, cols) {
  return flatten(zip(...chunk(a, (a.length/cols))))
}

let output = orderByCols(arr, 3);
```

**Live Code:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/order-by-cols

The problem comes in when we chunk the array and there is a remainder:

```
const remainderArr = ['abcdefghijklm'].split(''); // added 'm'
```

This throws everything in disarray.

The expected output would look like:

```
 ['a','f','j',
  'b','g','k',
  'c','h','l',
  'd','i','m',
  'e']
```

**Question:** How can I handle this scenario for collections that have remainders? Is my approach totally off?

Comment: Only lodash solution?

Comment: Of course not. But just trying to flex the lib for excerize

Answer (score 0):

I think you gots a bug

`Math.ceil(a.length/cols)`

---

I'm assuming your expected shape is off - since you're doing column-first ordering, really you should expect this solution:

`['a','f','k',
  'b','g','l',
  'c','h','m',
  'd','i',,
  'e','j',,]`

(which `Math.ceil` will get for you).

Either way, you'll need the ceiling in there to fix the resulting shape of the 2D array. You have an actual bug in your code.

---

If your expected result isn't off, and you're actually looking to "overflow" from the "middle" of the string, then there is no elegant solution for your problem - you'll have to manually figure out the overflow first, then use the elegant solution after having removed that part of the string

Comment: Math.ceil() would help remove nulls and such but my expected shape isn't off. >_<

Comment: It looks liek https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2641 last comment is talking about what I'm trying to do which kerrik called 
"columnize" using the partition function... but it doesn't work right now.

Comment: You're doing column - first ordering for the string, so the shape you're expecting is off.  With that sort, the more natural shape would have `j` in the bottom most row of the second column, not the top of the third column - and `Math.ceil()` fixes for that shape. I really don't understand why would ever want a mid-string character to overflow the way it does in your expected answer - it's very unnatural (and unlikely!) - but if that's what you want, then there's no elegant solution